# No Accounts to Log in With?

Tags: login

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the only accounts I have to select from to log in are "Administrator" and "Guest".  "Guest" has no real rights to anything and I have no password for "Administrator".

If I enter the recovery mode and the root console it does not "find" the "passwd" command if I try to reset the root (Administrator?) password.  It also does not "find" the `sudo` command.  I have no way at all of logging in with the Administrator account and the Guest account is useless.

Right now, my installation of Ubuntu is about as useful as a brick.  If the "Administrator" account (is this "root") is only there for the system to use, then why is it listed for logging in upon boot?  And if the "Guest" account cannot create a regular account or a USER administrator account (it would be ridiculous if it could) then how do you create such accounts?  I'd like to disable the Guest account and I'd like the only login accounts listed at startup to be accounts you can actually log in with.

Comment: First of all, a step-by-step protocol of what you did when installing ubuntu would be nice, as this seems like it is very unusual behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You had to have created a password during installation--if you were not the one who installed the system, ask for the password from the person who did. There is no default password. See this post for reset instructions (though since you said you just installed the system, it may be easier for you to simply re-install it): [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) Hope this helps!